# ListView с двумя полями

Tags: java, android-studio, listview

Пишу приложение в котором будут выводиться временные промежутки, поскольку их будет много решил сделать нумерацию через таблицы, в итоге при добавление 10, 100 и т.д. записии колонка увеличивается, а в месте с ней и отступ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После попробовал через `GridLayout` но там ситуация была та же.

После мой взор пал на `ListView`, но я столкнулся с проблемой что я не понимаю как вывести сразу 2 элемента в 1 строку, а коды из других источников у меня не работают.

Внимание вопрос: Как можно вывести 2 ячейчи текстового поля в 1 строку `ListView` или любой другой инструмент без отступа от чисел 10,100 и т.д.?

**UDP**
Ошибка:

> 2019-08-18 05:34:33.640 26339-26339/com.github.myapplicatiokek E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.github.myapplicatiokek, PID: 26339
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.github.myapplicatiokek/com.github.myapplicatiokek.Activitys}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.github.myapplicatiokek.Activitys" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3184)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
>   2019-08-18 05:34:33.665 26339-26339/com.github.myapplicatiokek E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.github.myapplicatiokek.Activitys" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>           at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
>           at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:43)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1243)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3172)
>               ... 11 more
>           Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.github.myapplicatiokek-0vZzwZCoBl_jWpnGF0gIMA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:365)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:107)
>           at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:80)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:444)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:403)
>           at dalvik.system.DexPathList.(DexPathList.java:164)
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:126)
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:101)
>           at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.(PathClassLoader.java:74)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:87)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:116)
>           at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:114)
>           at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:60)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:851)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:950)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1188)
>           at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2462)
>           at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2454)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6306)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:220)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1852)
>                   ... 6 more

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу 3 варианта.

1. Использовать конкатенацию строк;
2. Сверстать свой макет и написать свой адаптер для `ListView` (как это сделать можно узнать в [статье](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/113-urok-54-kastomizatsija-spiska-sozdaem-svoj-adapter.html));
3. Если Вы всё-таки выводите данные табличного формата, поискать готовые виджеты таблиц под Android на том же GitHub.

Первый вариант - костыль. Но, для простейших случаев, может и сойдёт. Второй и третий варианты сложнее, но зато результат более качественный.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, я считаю, необходимо создать макет самого элемента списка:

**item_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/text1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textSize="15sp"
             android:textColor="#000000" />

         <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textSize="15sp"
             android:textColor="#000000"
             android:text=") " />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/text2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textSize="15sp"
             android:textColor="#000000" />

  </LinearLayout >
```

После переходим к активности:

**Activitys.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.content.Context;

public class Activitys extends Activity{

    ListView list;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    String[] datas1 = new String[]{}; //то, что перед скобкой
    String[] datas2 = new String[]{}; //то, что после скобки

    private class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

          private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

          ListViewAdapter(Context context){
              mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
          };

          @Override
          public int getCount(){
              return datas2.length;
          };

          @Override
          public Object getItem(int position){
              return position;
          };

          @Override
          public long getItemId(int position){
              return position;
          };

          @Override
          public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
              if (convertView == null) convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);
             TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
             text1.setText(datas1[position]);
             TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
             text2.setText(datas2[position]);
             return convertView;
         };

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(Activitys.this);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    };

}
```

И, собственно, макет всего списка:

**list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"        
    android:layout_width="match_parent"        
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

         <ListView
             android:id="@+id/list"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout >
```

P.S. пишите в комментарии об ошибках

**UPDATE**

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.YOUR_PACKAGE.YOUR_NAME">

//Исправьте YOUR_PACKAGE и YOUR_NAME на ваши

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activitys" />
//Здесь же указываются и другие используемые активности
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97564/discussion-on-answer-by---listview---).